# Why does Jules use gay men to "conquer femininity"?

Tags: character, analysis, euphoria

Jules is one of the main characters of the *Euphoria* series - she is transgender (male to female), but it is implied that she went through with her transition and now no one, including homophobic characters, calls her other than "she".

According to her own words, she is trying to "conquer femininity":

> [Jules] - I remember walking out of Sears with
> my first pair of heels in my backpack. And I got home,
> and went straight to my room locked the door, put 'em on... 
> And, I just... felt like... I was collecting herbs, or making potions in order
> to up my manna [SIC], you know?
> Like, it started with that,
> and then it was clothes, and then it was makeup,
> and eventually hormones. Um, I just kind of kept leveling up 
> -So, what level are you at now? 
> [Jules] -I don't know. But I definitely haven't reached
> my full power. 
> -But you date guys, right? 
> [Jules] -Date isn't really the right word [...] my relationship to men is weird. In my head, it's like... **If I can conquer men, then I can conquer femininity.**[...]But, it's not like I even want to conquer it. It's like I want to fuckin' obliterate it. And then move on to the next level

After her surgeries she starts sleeping around... but she uses GRINDR, the dating app for gay men, who still treat her as a male. I am not transgender, but this is a bit confusing to me - why isn't she trying to find a heterosexual man, who would treat her as a woman?

Comment: Not an answer because just a theory, but I suspect it is because she doesn't really feel like she is a 'true' female yet. She hasn't reached her full power; she needs to keep levelling up; she still hasn't conquered femininity. These phrases all shout out insecurity. I suspect she still has issues with her identity, and if she even deserves to be treated as a female yet. Keeping her dating pool to gay men is her way of avoiding facing her fears, and possibly punishing herself at the same time for those fears. In short, it's complicated.

Comment: @WolfieSmith that is... actually a pretty good answer

Comment: Also add to this her skewed version of what it means to be a female in a male-driven world, and she doesn't even know if that is a role she wants to fill herself, hence the reference to obliterating femininity and moving on to the next level. Jules isn't male, but she doesn't particularly want to be 'female' either, with all its connotations. In short, it's complicated

Comment: I haven't watched the show, so this isn't an answer, but to correct a possible misconception Grindr isn't just for gay men. That's how it started, and how it tends to be promoted but anyone can use it. Some trans people find that using a more queer-focused app makes it easier to find accepting partners.